# Visual response for loading pages in pwa

Tags: css, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to let PWA users know that a clicked link is being loaded. Usually in the browser we see the blue progress line indicating this but in the pwa the user is left to assume the page is loading except there is a pseudo effect on the buttons programmed by the developer. I understand the idea behind pwa includes giving users immersive visuals and if pages load faster, the users will not bother about the blue line but sometimes it's needed.

Comment: You may refer with this [blog](https://medium.com/@owencm/designing-great-uis-for-progressive-web-apps-dd38c1d20f7) which stated that screen transitions shouldn’t feel slow due to blocking on the network. When a user taps a button or link in a web app, especially a server rendered web app, they are often made to wait staring at the current screen before suddenly jumping to a whole new screen of content. This feels unresponsive and is unacceptable in a PWA (Progressive Web App) since betrays the idea that the app itself is running locally on the device.

Comment: Aim to provide the perception that the whole “app” is stored locally on the phone and that only the content is being dynamically loaded. Try to use a cache-first network strategy wherever possible as network-first strategies cause severe performance issues on slow or flaky networks.

Comment: Okay, I've thought about the whole service worker caching first then network approach and that does work. Thanks for the blog link, it's super helpful. I guess it's up to us to make the PWA feel native.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the same thing but i think i found a way.
We can use bootstrap spinners to animate this. We can use javascript to detect a link click and show the spinner. We can also add this on submit button click.